# C syntax checker using Java

Tags: java, c, api, syntax

For my java project I need to check a code written in C for errors and syntax ... Is there any API or anyother Java implementation of C syntax and error checker?

Comment: Java uses C synthax so if java fails, C fails.

Comment: Invoke a C compiler and see if it returned 0 exit code? :)

Comment: @Shark: that's deep — it was never the case.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I want to display the errors to the user.. If I use a compiler then how can I do that

Comment: @SaiSunder: Re-direct the output of a compiler? :)

Comment: classic coder comedy right here :)))

Comment: How do i redirect the output of a compiler? And are u talking about gnu/gcc compiler?

Comment: @SaiSunder: Have considered reading some book about programming?

Comment: @VladLazarenko I Have used only IDEs for compilation.. never tried like what u r saying

Answer (score 4):

You could invoke a C compiler in Java and parse the results.

An alternative could be [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/api), since they offer an [API](http://ideone.com/api).

> **What is ideone?**
>   Ideone is something more than a pastebin; it's an online compiler and
>   debugging tool which allows to compile and run code online in more
>   than 40 programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty broad, but it looks like [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) might be the tool you need.  There's a load of [grammars](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) available, including one for C.

Answer (score 1):

Real answer:

i used to do something liek this a few years ago... basically you need JFlex and CUP or some form of a scanner/parser combo.

take a look, i don't think i have the finished thing uploaded but you can take it from there... http://code.google.com/p/javamicko/

Answer (score 1):

Coco/R[1] is a LL1 compiler generator available in Java.

You can define a language by your own (tokens + syntax) and parse/check a given input.

[1] http://ssw.jku.at/Coco/